# C++ passing a function pointer twice causing issues

Tags: c++, pointers, pthreads

I have a function pointer that I am trying to pass along to a class method, where pthread_create will be invoked to pass along that parameter. But I am getting some errors and not sure where I am suppose to go from here.

```
void (*FuncPointer)(void*);
FuncPointer = random_function;
ThreadPool.Task(FuncPointer);
```

```
int IOThreadPool::Task(void* (*FuncPointer)(void*))
{
    pthread_t NewThread;

    int rc = pthread_create(&NewThread, NULL, FuncPointer, (void *) (intptr_t) IOThreadPool::Threads.size() + 1);
```

`main.cpp:57:29: error: invalid conversion from ‘void* (*)()’ to ‘void (*)(void*)’ [-fpermissive]`

Please explain why even though I am passing it as `void* (*)(void*)`, I get `void* (*)()`. I am very confused and my head has begun to hurt!

Thanks

Comment: could you provide random_function too? It has the correct signature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
invalid conversion from ‘void* (*)()’ to ‘void (*)(void*)’
```

You forgot to show us the declaration of `random_function`, but judging from the error message, it appears to be

```
void* ranfom_function()
```

Since the signature of the function does not match the signature of `FuncPointer` (`ranfom_function` lacks the argument , and return type is different), you get the error.

---

Another bug, that is not shown by the error: The return type of `FuncPointer` does not match the return type of the argument accepted by `IOThreadPool::Task` (void vs void*).

---

Solution: Declare instad

```
void* ranfom_function(void*)
```

and

```
void* (*FuncPointer)(void*)
```

Comment: You're the man. This was it. Thank you for explaining that to me... You also just shed a new light on this concept for me. I understand now why it wasn't working. Cheers to you!